# HTML - Center Div not Working with Position Relative

Tags: html, css, position, center

I am trying to center a div on page, but its not working.

I need to use Position: Relative on the style of the div, because if I don't use it, the entire div won't appear on page!

Here is the style right now:

```
#page-wrap {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 300;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px 50px;

    border-left: 10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-right: 10px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}
```

The div is appearing on the top of the page, centered horizontally, but I want to center it vertically...

How can I do it?

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: can u post ur code in a fiddle

Comment: This link at the end shows what you need to do.  Basically you need to wrap that div inside another div and position the wrapper to relative.  http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: Hey guys, this is the fiddle you requested http://jsfiddle.net/k5yYL/, having my code and the CSS. I can't put the page-wrap div centered vertically :s

Can someone help me? Thanks alot !

Comment: @Kevin Zaki I made a div using the class Absolute-Center, from the link you posted, to wrap my page-wrap div, but still didn't work..